# Are there any churches that claim to be Sola Sciptura that also are pro gay-marriage?

Tags: marriage, homosexuality

A friend of mine has posited that it is impossible to be Sola Scriptura and also be pro gay-marriage.

I think he is right in a traditional sense. However, I am curious to know if there any churches that claim to be 'Sola Sciptura' that also are pro gay-marriage?

And if so, do they have any doctrinal statement that addresses the concern that conflict might create for some people.

Answers:

Ben Miller below has answered that the Evangelical Lutheran Church in America claims to be Sola Scriptura and also pro gay-marriage.

Of course, please keep coming with answers if there are other churches that do the same.

Comment: The Roman Catholic Church is not for same-sex marriage, and it is certainly not sola scriptura.

Comment: It's important to recognize that "sola scriptura" does not dictate the degree to which one holds scripture to be "literal." One can hold to the concept of sola scriptura, and still take a more relativistic or liberal view of scripture. I suspect your friend was confusing the concepts of sola scriptura and Bible literalism.

Answer (score 7):

The Evangelical Lutheran Church in America (ELCA) [elected an openly gay bishop](https://web.archive.org/web/20131112083447/http://www.elca.org/Who-We-Are/Our-Three-Expressions/Churchwide-Organization/Communication-Services/News/Releases.aspx?a=5300) earlier this year.  [On their website, they claim](https://web.archive.org/web/20130616205538/http://www.elca.org/What-We-Believe/The-Basics/What-Lutherans-Believe.aspx) to "hold to the basic principles of Luther’s theological teachings, such as **Grace alone, faith alone, Scripture alone.**"

Comment: Wow! That is exactly what I was looking for. And they also have a very comprehensive section on their website outlining what they believe about sexuality and why they think it is scriptural. Thanks for submitting this answer.